# Update Multiple Rows with Multiple Conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have code like this to update multiple rows

```
--ZZSEQUENCENBR
UPDATE AUSP 
SET CharacteristicValue = SUBSTRING(@RolNum, 5, 1) 
WHERE Object = @Batch AND Internalcharno = 'ZZSEQUENCENBR'

--ZZPOSITIONMS
UPDATE AUSP  
SET CharacteristicValue = SUBSTRING(@RolNum, 6, 1) 
WHERE Object = @Batch AND Internalcharno = 'ZZPOSITIONMS'

--ZZDERIVATIVEMS
UPDATE AUSP SET CharacteristicValue = SUBSTRING(@RolNum,7,1) WHERE Object = @Batch AND Internalcharno = 'ZZDERIVATIVEMS'
--ZZPOSITIONSS
UPDATE AUSP SET CharacteristicValue = SUBSTRING(@RolNum,8,1) WHERE Object = @Batch AND Internalcharno = 'ZZPOSITIONSS'
--ZZDERIVATIVESS
UPDATE AUSP SET CharacteristicValue = SUBSTRING(@RolNum,9,1) WHERE Object = @Batch AND Internalcharno = 'ZZDERIVATIVESS'
--ZZNOMORROLL
UPDATE AUSP SET CharacteristicValue = @RolNum WHERE Object = @Batch AND Internalcharno = 'ZZNOMORROLL'

--UPDATE Speed
UPDATE AUSP SET Valuefrom = @SPEED WHERE Object = @Batch AND InternalCharNo = 'ZZSPEED'
--Update Panjang, Lebar, berat & Xtra Length
UPDATE AUSP SET Valuefrom = @LebarActual WHERE Object = @Batch AND InternalCharNo = 'ZZWIDTH'
UPDATE AUSP SET Valuefrom = @PanjangActual WHERE Object = @Batch AND InternalCharNo = 'ZZLENGTH'    
SELECT @Thick = ZZTYPEFILM.[ThicknessFilm(Micron)], @Density = ZZTYPEFILM.[Density(g/Cm3)] FROM (SELECT CharacteristicValue FROM AUSP WHERE (InternalCharNo = N'ZZCODE') AND (Object = @Batch)) AS View1 INNER JOIN ZZTYPEFILM ON View1.CharacteristicValue = ZZTYPEFILM.KodeFilm
SET @QtyRol = ROUND((@LebarActual * @PanjangActual * convert(float,@Thick) * convert(float,@density))/1000000,1) 
UPDATE AUSP SET Valuefrom = @QtyRol WHERE Object = @Batch AND InternalCharNo = 'ZZCONVERSIONROLLKG'
UPDATE AUSP SET Valuefrom = @XtraPanjang WHERE Object = @Batch AND InternalCharNo = 'ZZEXLENGTH'
```

I was try code like this to update Internalcharno, not yet in Valuefrom :

```
UPDATE AUSP
SET CharacteristicValue = (case when Internalcharno = 'ZZPRODLINE' then 'EDIT'
                        when Internalcharno = 'ZZMONTHYEAR' then 'EDIT1'
                        when Internalcharno = 'ZZSEQUENCENBR' then 'EDIT2'
                        when Internalcharno = 'ZZPOSITIONMS' then 'EDIT3'
                        when Internalcharno = 'ZZDERIVATIVEMS' then 'EDIT4'
                        when Internalcharno = 'ZZPOSITIONSS' then 'EDIT5'
                        when Internalcharno = 'ZZDERIVATIVESS' then 'EDIT6'
                        when Internalcharno = 'ZZNOMORROLL' then 'EDIT7'
                end)
WHERE Internalcharno in ('ZZPRODLINE', 'ZZMONTHYEAR', 'ZZSEQUENCENBR', 'ZZPOSITIONMS', 
'ZZDERIVATIVEMS', 'ZZPOSITIONSS', 'ZZDERIVATIVESS', 'ZZNOMORROLL' ) AND
        [Object] = '414095';
```

But this code throws an error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure HistoryAUSPBeforeUpdate, Line 27
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Can anyone help? Thanks,

Comment: I think the error is coming from one of the updates in the first set.  In your second update, the `CASE` expression is not needed, and you could just assign `Internalcharno` directly to `EDIT`.

Comment: I think error fro here : `FROM (SELECT CharacteristicValue FROM AUSP WHERE (Inte`, you have to apply TOP 1 OR update where condition where it return only one record

Comment: Can you @TimBiegeleisen expain me about `the CASE expression is not needed` ?

Comment: you need to keep where condition values in a table variable then try it..

Answer (score 1):

As You changed your question,I think problem is not in your last update query but somewhere here:

```
SELECT @Density = ZZTYPEFILM.[Density(g/Cm3)]
FROM (SELECT CharacteristicValue FROM AUSP WHERE (InternalCharNo = N'ZZCODE') 
AND (Object = @Batch)) AS View1 INNER JOIN ZZTYPEFILM ON View1.CharacteristicValue = ZZTYPEFILM.KodeFilm
```

Make sure your every subquery is giving you a single value.

Comment: Pardon me, the values is not equal in every Internalcharno condition